# Laravel error in login route when the user is authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, token

I have a Laravel app with an Auth system created by `php artisan make:auth` command.

To login, I go to **localhost/app/login**, submit the form and the app redirects me to **localhost/app/admin**. Everything is fine. But when I try to visit **localhost/app/login** after logging in, I get the error:

```
'Trying to get property of non-object' in '…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php 158
```

How can I make the app redirect me to a different page if the user is already logged in? Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code related on this?